# Understanding why Split Polygon tool is greyed out?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, editing

I have a wetlands dataset (blue in the pic below) and a parcel dataset (green). I would like to clip the parcel dataset where it intersects the wetlands dataset, so that the parcel layer will be empty where the wetlands go through.

The Advanced Editing tool 'Split Polygons' seems to be my best option, but it is greyed out. I have an advanced license, so I know that's not the issue.

Does anyone know what could be causing this to happen?

[image: Description of Issue]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The split polygons tool may not be the best option for your intent.

The Erase tool would work better for processing a large quantity of polygons. To access the Erase tool, go to "Geoprocessing" in the header menu and click on "Search for Tools". The "Erase (Analysis)" tool will perform the task described.

Comment: The erase tool was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! I edited my answer if anyone else needs to know how to find the Erase tool.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to erase the watercourses you will need to [buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000019000000) the line features to erase them from your parcels.

[Cut polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q800000104000000) is an interactive tool so expect to do a *lot* of clicking, conversely you can [union](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000s000000) your parcels and wetlands and remove the features that have a wetland ID. Union is limited to two input feature classes with a basic or standard license.

If you're trying to remove waterbodies (poly) and watercourses (line) buffer the watercourses by an acceptable amount then [merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000055000000) with waterbodies prior to union.

Union and delete method will work with basic and standard license levels but should you have an advanced license you can replace union and delete with ID with [erase tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000m000000).